# Spring boot application not starting on Tomcat 7

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-social

I am trying to deploy my Spring boot application on a Tomcat 7 server and start it. I am able to deploy, while I am facing problems in starting the server.

What I did ?

1) Created a spring starter project with the initial configurations and dependencies.

2) Edited the 'org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml' file and changed the 'jst.web' version from 3.1 to 3.0. Cleaned the project.

3) Implemented `ServletContextInitializer` with onStartup method override based on the explicit configuration steps as per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/522. Code looks like below

```
@Configuration
public class ContextInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

and in my Application class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(new Class[] { SocialIntegrationApplication.class, ContextInitializer.class }, args);
}
```

4) Performed a mvn clean install. Builds successfully.

But when starting the server, I am getting an error as `Server Java Web Tomcat 7 Server failed to start.`

Could you please help me out. Thanks.

EDIT : Sharing the catalina.out. Not able to see any error though.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:16:17 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 899
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:16:18 +0530] "GET /ROOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37264
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:16:19 +0530] "GET /ROOT/pages/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 923
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:17 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 899
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:18 +0530] "GET /ROOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37264
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:18 +0530] "GET /ROOT/pages/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 923
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:27 +0530] "GET /ROOT/facebook HTTP/1.1" 200 37264
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:27 +0530] "GET /ROOT/pages/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 923
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:38 +0530] "GET /ROOT/facebook HTTP/1.1" 200 37264
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:22:38 +0530] "GET /ROOT/pages/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 923
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:25:17 +0530] "GET /ROOT/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37264
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:25:17 +0530] "GET /ROOT/pages/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 923
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:25:59 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 899
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:26:00 +0530] "GET /integration/ HTTP/1.1" 404 923
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:28:31 +0530] "GET /integration/ HTTP/1.1" 404 923
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:29:02 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 899
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Feb/2017:18:29:05 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 899
```

Sharing the server console log

```
    15:27:19.848 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
15:27:19.852 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/XM/neo-java-web-sdk-2.53.6/repository/.archive/bin/logback-classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
15:27:19.852 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/XM/XM_Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/social-integration/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
15:27:19.853 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
15:27:20.269 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

EDIT 2 : Adding the `logging.level.root=INFO` to the properties file, getting the following exception

```
    11:53:20.995 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
11:53:20.997 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/XM/neo-java-web-sdk-2.53.6/repository/.archive/bin/logback-classic.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
11:53:20.997 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/XM/XM_Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/social-integration-tomcat7/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
11:53:20.998 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
11:53:21.283 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.slf4j.helpers.Util - SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
11:53:22.303 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable - java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
11:53:22.303 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
11:53:22.304 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)
11:53:22.304 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
11:53:22.304 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
11:53:22.304 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:841)
11:53:22.305 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:185)
11:53:22.305 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.fatal(DirectJDKLog.java:161)
11:53:22.305 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)
11:53:22.305 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:53:22.306 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
11:53:22.306 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:53:22.306 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
11:53:22.307 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
11:53:22.307 [main] ERROR java.lang.Throwable -     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
```

and my current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.xm</groupId>
<artifactId>social-integration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>social-integration</name>
<description>Social integration using Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Facebook APIs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.facebook.ads.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>facebook-java-ads-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: There must be more informations in the catalina.out logfile. Please take a lokk and post it here

Comment: Judging by the `ClassCircularityError` it looks like the dependency on `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` is the problem

Answer (score 2):

## Spring Boot and Tomcat 7

### pom.xml

#### version specification:

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.78</tomcat.version>
    <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
</properties>
```

#### dependencies downgrade:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>  <!-- provided: tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope> <!-- runtime: tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- remove it:
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
</dependencies>
```

### Traditional deployment

To create a deployable war file (Tomcat 7) read this guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

- `<packaging>war</packaging>`
- override: `SpringBootServletInitializer.configure`:

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
          return application.sources(Application.class);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following to your pom.xml and try,

```
<properties>
        <tomcat.version>your tomcat version</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Added. But still the same problem !

Comment: Which is the logger you are using? is it possible to include your pom.xml. or check is there any multiple dependecies for slf4j.