# Cannot run Spring Boot 2.0 on Tomcat7: "Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean."

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat7

I need to run my spring boot 2.0 aplication on tomcat 7

And I'm getting this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project Demo: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Demo</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.78</tomcat.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>  <!-- provided: tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope> <!-- runtime: tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- remove it:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My main DemoApplication.java file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and ServletInitializer.java file

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

If i run this aplication in tomcat8 without this 2 lines in pom.xml

```
<tomcat.version>7.0.78</tomcat.version>
<servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
```

which I included because of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394772/5861265 and with this dependency for tomcat

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

everything is working properly

But I need to run this 2.0 app on tomcat 7 if it is possible, so I'm interested if there is any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Comment: Why are you not using embedded tomcat container?

Comment: I am new with tomcat, but I think that we are not using embedded tomcat container because standalone containers can host multiple java deployments

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463908/unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-servletwebserv?

Comment: Yes, I did. And also tried with compile scope, but same error

Comment: Why don't you use embedded tomcat container? If you would like to run two spring boot applications same time then use different ports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.0 (and Spring Framework 5 upon which it builds) requires a Servlet 3.1 compatible container. Tomcat 7 only implements Servlet 3.0 so it cannot be used with Spring Boot 2.0.